# Trying to animate a divs height with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I'm trying to animate a divs height, and at the same time set the bottom property. The animation works, but it doesn't remain at the bottom of the "parent" div.

Here is the code for the animation:

```
function mini(elem) {
        var val = 200;
        var elm = document.getElementById(elem.id);

        function frame() {
            val--;

            elm.setAttribute("style", "height:" + val + "px;bottom:0px;");

            if (val == 80) {
                clearInterval(id);
            }
        }

        var id = setInterval(frame, 1);            
    }
```

You can see the entire HTML here: http://test.lundbeckconsulting.no/ContentBox/default.html

Comment: Is jQuery's `.animate()` out of the question?

Comment: nope! I'm reading about it now. and I'm wondering if the animation will be faster? even when I set it to 1ms its too slow in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `bottom:0px` on an element with `position:relative`. This does nothing.

---

You should probably look into using jQuery `.animate()`. You can do the same feature without worrying about pesky timer intervals, etc. Your entire code up top could be simplified to this:

`$('#container').animate({'height':0},200,'linear');`

Comment: thanks! it looks better now, the animation is smoother

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are calling `mini()` on the wrong element.  It should be called on `container_sub`, not `container`.

Answer (score 0):

The given full example inside doesn't give a clear understanding which is though as the parent and which is child.

There are 2 easy ways of doing the effect you desire:

1. Add margin-top to the child so it moves down the same as the height decreases
2. Parent element needs to be `position: relative` while the child needs to be `position: absolute` for the bottom to work here

Sidenote #1: Make code more readable by changing dom element style with its style property. And by doing this you won't need to set bottom style on each animation frame.

```
//From
elm.setAttribute("style", "height:" + val + "px;bottom:0px;");
// To
elm.style.height = val + 'px';
elm.style.bottom = '0px';
```

Sidenote #2: read about using [Window.requestAnimationFrame()](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) for animating within javascipt.
Sidenote #3: try to do animation within css using a combination of transform and transition and listen to the end of animation withing javascript.

Comment: now I've using jquery, and it almost works. but when I move the mouse around sometimes the animation goes up and down. http://test.lundbeckconsulting.no/ContentBox/default.html

Comment: It is because jQuery animations are queued, you need to clear the queue before starting the new animation instance.